# Devise doesn't sign in after sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I have subclassed RegistrationsController so that I can build in a payment form using Stripe. I've put the Stripe code in the create method and when I sign up it creates the Stripe customer without any problems. However I'm not logged in after the registration completes and the user is not created as I can't login.

Code is below (I've left out the Stripe code as it doesn't seem relevant but I can post it if needed).

```
    build_resource
resource.role = params[:selectplan]
resource.admin = false 
resource.customer_id = customer.id
if resource.save
  Notifier.signup_email(@user).deliver
  if resource.active_for_authentication?
    set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  else
    set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  end
else
  clean_up_passwords resource
  respond_with resource
end
```

Comment: Is it actually hitting the `sign_in(resource_name, resource)` line?

Comment: @Beerlington I'm still learning the ropes with rails. How do I test that? Normally I'd set a breakpoint but that doesn't seem possible with rails.

Comment: you can either use the debugger gem, pry gem, or just do `puts "here"` right above that line.

Comment: The RailsApps project has a good open source example app that shows how to use Devise with Stripe, have you seen it? http://railsapps.github.io/rails-stripe-membership-saas/

Comment: @Beerlington Thanks. I've tried using puts and logger in my controller but neither show up in the developer.log (even if I put them at the start of the create method).

Comment: @DanielKehoe Thanks, checking it out now.

Comment: @Beerlington Ok, at if resource.save it jumps to the else clean_up_passwords

Comment: I think I've narrowed down the problem. I'm recently updated to Rails 4 but it no longer supports attr_accessible which I'm using in my models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resource wasn't saving as I was still using attr_accessible which Rails 4 and Devise don't support. I switched to using Strong Parameters and it is now working correctly again.